How to configure postgres / pgbouncer in a serverless environment
i read several articles/posts but for me it is not very clear what is important for the configuration of a selfhosted postgres + pgbouncer when using a serverless approach for the application itself.
My application runs serverless in aws with a single lambda-function and connects to a postgres database running on a hetzner VPS. Due to the serverless nature there are sometimes 50 concurrent lambda-functions running...
The configuration which is not clear to me is about the max-connections from postgres and default_pool_size/max_client_conn from pgbouncer. I guess it also depends on how many connections to the database a single lambda-instance will open. As i am using typeorm inside i think the default here is 10 connections. Maybe i should also adjust this value?
I hope someone could lead me into the right direction and give me some tips on best approaches here..
